# Iterating through an array out of arrays using N1QL

Tags: java, sql++

Given the following Java code:

```
String statement = "SELECT `path` FROM test-bucket;";
N1qlQueryResult queryResult = bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(statement);

for (N1qlQueryRow n1qlQueryRow : queryResult) {
  System.out.println(n1qlQueryRow.toString());
}
```

And the test-bucket on Couchbase containing only json-files structured like the following example:

```
{
  "path": "C:\\example\\filename.txt",
  "outer_array": [
    {
      "inner_array": [
        {
            "value": 1,
        },
        {
            "value": 2,
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "inner_array": [
        {
            "value": 3,
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to iterate trough the `outer_array` and each `value` of each `inner_array` with a simple string. If at least one value satisfies a condition from the `statement`
, the `path` should be added to the `queryResult`.
The `statement` should look something like this (this example is wrong):

```
statement = "SELECT `path` FROM test-bucket WHERE outer_array.inner_array.value=1;";
```

But this obviously does not work. So what I have to do, to check each `value`?

Comment: Since the inner array is an *array*, I think you can use `WHERE 1 IN outer_array.inner_array`

Comment: This does not work for me. There are no errors and the `queryResult` is empty after running the code.

Comment: Ah right. Didn't realize there was a JSON object instead of simply an array of values. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT `path`
FROM `test-bucket`
WHERE ANY oa IN outer_array SATISFIES (ANY ia IN oa.inner_array SATISFIES ia.`value` = 1 END) END;
```